# sed + un-comment parameter and change value in file

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

I want to uncomment the wal_level parameter and change the value from minimal to  archive

how to perform this action by sed / perl one-liner ?

```
$ grep wal_level  /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
#wal_level = minimal                    # minimal, archive, or hot_standby
```

expected results:

```
  wal_level = archive                    # minimal, archive, or hot_standby
```

Note that `wal_level` could be couple of spaces from the "#".

For example:

```
#     wal_level = minimal
```

or

```
#       wal_level = minimal
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pi.BAK -aF'/(\h*[#=]\h*)/,$_,4' -le '
   $F[4] = "archive";
   $_ = join $,, @F[2..$#F] if /^\h*#\h*wal_level\h*=/;
' /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

The line is split into fields `@F` and the delimiters are included as well.
The parameter 4 in the field split option `-F` will constrain the number of fields to that. The fields from 3rd onwards are joined together using empty space, which is the default value of the `OFS = $,`

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
sed 's/^ *# *wal_level *= *[^ ]*/wal_level = archive/'
```

I also allow for a space before the comment (just in case) and 0 or more spaces everywhere else. Alternatively, in perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^\s*#\s*wal_level\s*=\s*\S+/wal_level = archive/' file
```

Comment: regarding perl - how to save the changes , I try with i flag but not works

Comment: you have mistake its should be - sed -i 's/^ *# *wal_level *= *[^ ]*/wal_level = archive/'  file

Comment: another thing its remove the second  #  (    # minimal, archive, or hot_standby  )

Comment: @yael the `-i` flag does work, it actually originates in perl, that's where `sed` took it from. Change the `-pe` to `-i -pe` and it will work. And thanks, I changed the `minimal` to `archive`. I don't understand what you mean with your last comment. Both solutions here only affect the first `#`. The `# minimal, archive, or hot_standby ` is not changed.

Comment: its remove also the second "#" that should be as comment , I will check this again

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the whole line where `wal_level` appears, including the `#` and an arbitrary number of whitespaces:

```
sed '/^# *wal_level/cwal_level = archive' inputfile
```

Comment: That removes the comment after the value though.